# Как реализовать вертикальную шкалу с номерами на HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: Требуется ваш совет, каким образом лучше реализовать такой список по середине с цифрами? Html и Css]

Требуется ваш совет, каким образом лучше реализовать такой список по середине с цифрами? Html и Css

Comment: Это называется `Vertical Timeline`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: tomato;
}
ol {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  counter-reset: count;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
ol:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 80%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
ol > li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-right: calc(50% + 28px);
}
ol > li:nth-child(even) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: calc(50% + 28px);
}
ol > li:before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content: counter(count)" ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -14px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: tomato;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Как реализовать такой список с номерами на Html и Css</li>
  <li>Как реализовать такой список с номерами на Html и Css</li>
  <li>Как реализовать такой список с номерами на Html и Css</li>
  <li>Как реализовать такой список с номерами на Html и Css</li>
  <li>Как реализовать такой список с номерами на Html и Css</li>
  <li>Как реализовать такой список с номерами на Html и Css</li>
  <li>Как реализовать такой список с номерами на Html и Css</li>
  <li>Как реализовать такой список с номерами на Html и Css</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: С float'ами было бы проще, наверное?

Comment: @Qwertiy - вариант с float  - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/p2xj0kf6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Нумерацию можно сгенерировать при помощи CSS свойств [`counter*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)
Таким образом удастся отдельно стилизовать счетчик. Также придется отдельно стилизовать четные и нечетные элементы, но это уже при помощи `:nth-child()`

Все это поддерживается в текущих версиях браузеров